# How to create a Template driven formArray in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-template-form

I have a fix number of checkbox which I am binding using for loop.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let chk of checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" [id]="chk.id" [value]="chk.value"/>
        <label [for]="chk.id">{{chk.name}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

what I am looking for is using template driven form to get a value all of selected checkboxes, something like following

```
{
    selected:[
        checkboxValue1,
        checkboxValue2,
        checkboxValue3,
    ]
}
```

NOTE:

I am able to use Reactive form to generate a FormGroup->FormArray which generates the following form value

```
{
    checkboxes:[
        {
            id: checkboxId1,
            value: checkboxValue1,
            selected: true,
        },
        {
            id: checkboxId2,
            value: checkboxValue2,
            selected: false,
        },
        {
            id: checkboxId3,
            value: checkboxValue3,
            selected: true,
        }
    ]
}
```

Which I am then filtering out with selected==true.

I was wondering how to do something similar with template driven form.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but you can bind your `chk.value` property like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-74836058?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a template variable to the checkbox and then query it using `@ViewChildren`

```js
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let chk of checkboxes">
        <input #checkbox type="checkbox" [id]="chk.id" [value]="chk.value"/>
        <label [for]="chk.id">{{chk.name}}</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then in your component class:

```js
export class MyComponent {
  @ViewChildren('checkbox')
  checkboxes!: QueryList<ElementRef>
}
```

And to access your array:

```js
const selected = this.checkboxes
      .map(t => t.nativeElement)
      .map(checkbox => checkbox.checked
```